# When does the product equal the sum?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and $R^n$ be the direct sum of $R$. Find all $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n \in R$ such that $$a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n = a_1a_2\cdots a_n,$$
or, in other words, if we let $$ K_n = \left\{ (a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n) \in R^n \, | \, a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n = a_1a_2\cdots a_n \right\},$$
we are interested in determining the algebraic nature of $K_n$.

> **Example 1:** Let $R = \mathbb{Z}$ and consider $\mathbb{Z}^3$; then we have the classic number theory problem of determining $a,b,c$ such that $$a + b + c= abc.$$ $(1,2,3)$ is one such solution to the problem.
>
> **Example 2:** Let $R = \mathbb{Z}[i]$ and consider $\mathbb{Z}[i]^3$; then this is a twist of the above example. One such solution is $(1-i, 1+i, 2)$.

For the purposes of notation, we will let $(a_i)$ be shorthand for $(a_i)_{i=1}^n$, $\sum_n a_i$ to denote $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$, and $\prod_n a_i$ denote $\prod_{i=1}^n a_i$. We will also say $(a_i)$ satisfies the *product-sum* property if $(a_i) \in K_n$.

By observation, we see that $0_{R^n} = (0_R) \in K_n$, so $K_n$ is non-empty.  In addition, if $S_n$ denotes the symmetric group on $\{1, \cdots, n\}$ and we define $\cdot: S_n \times K_n \to K_n$ by $\sigma \cdot (a_i) = (a_{\sigma(i)})$, which is defined since it follows by commutativity in $R$, we find $\cdot$ is a group action of $S_n$ on $K_n$. This means if we know $(a_i) \in K_n$, then this informs us that any permutation of the elements in $(a_i)$ will also be a solution to above property. Furthermore, if we let $Z_R  = \{\alpha \in R \, | \, \alpha^n = \alpha\}$, where $n$ is the same integer as indicated in $R^n$, we see, under multiplication $\cdot$ in $R$, that $(Z_R, \cdot)$ is a commutative monoid. Thus, if we define $\cdot: Z_R \times K_n \to K_n$ by $\alpha \cdot (a_i) = (\alpha a_i)$, which is defined since
$$\sum_n \alpha a_i = \alpha \sum_n a_i = \alpha \prod_n a_i = \alpha^n \prod_n a_i = \prod_n \alpha a_i,$$
we have $\cdot$ is a monoid action of $Z_R$ on $K_n$. This means if we know $(a_i) \in K_n$, i.e. $(a_i)$ is a solution to the above property, then $(\alpha a_i)$ is also a solution.

Let's write $K_n$ as a union of two sets $A$ and $B$, where $A$ is defined to be collection of elements $(a_i)$ such that $a_i = 0_R$ for at least one $i$, and $B$ is defined to be collection of elements $(a_i)$ such that $a_i \neq 0_R$ for any $i$; one way of thinking about is that the "trivial" solutions are packaged into $A$ and the "non-trivial" solutions are packaged into $B$. Then, by definition, $K_n$ is the disjoint union of $A$ and $B$, i.e. $K_n = A \sqcup B$.

Let's consider $A$; notice $A$ is non-empty since $(0) \in A$. Since at least one of $a_i = 0$, $\prod_n a_i = 0$. In addition, since we have a group action of $S_n$ on $K_n$, without loss of generality, we may assume $a_n = 0$. By this construction, we find $A$ is an additive abelian group; as a consequence, we can build an $R$-module structure on $A$ by defining $r \cdot (a_i) = (ra_i)$. Then an immediate consequence is that $A = \mathrm{Span}_R(\{E\})$, where $$E = \left\{(1,0,\cdots,0,-1, 0), (0,1,\cdots,0,-1, 0), \cdots, (0,0,\cdots,1,-1, 0) \right\}$$ with $|E| = n-2$. Since $E$ spans $A$ and the vectors are linearly independent over $R$, this means $A$ is a free $R$-module of finite rank, so that $A = \langle E \rangle$. Thus, $K_n = \langle E \rangle \sqcup B$.

Let's consider $B$; this structure is **MUCH** trickier to work with compared to $A$. If $\mathrm{char} \, R = 0$, then we at least know $B$ is non-empty; in particular, we have $(\overbrace{1,\cdots,1}^{n-2 \,  \textbf{times}},2,n) \in B $. However, if $\mathrm{char} \, R > 0$, then it's not immediately clear if $B$ is non-empty. That said, if we modify $Z_R$ such that we have $Z_R^* = \{\alpha \in R \, \backslash \{0\} \, | \, \alpha^{n} = \alpha\}$, then, continuing from the previous information given, we have $\cdot$ is a monoid action of $Z_R^*$ on $B$, so that we know if $(a_i) \in B$, then so is $(\alpha a_i) \in B$.

I am not sure how to proceed from here. Instead, I made additional assumptions on $R$; if $R$ is a unique factorization domain, then we have a way of classifying the elements in $B$, i.e. $(-1 + \prod_{n-1} a_i)a_n$ can be written as a product of powers of irreducibles with a unit. Since factorization in a UFD is...well, unique, that means we can associate such irreducibles to the elements $(-1 + \prod_{n-1} a_i)$ and $a_n$ and then determine $a_i$ from then on. However, if this assumption is alleviated, it is not clear how to determine $(a_i)$ in $B$. So this begs the following questions.

> **Question 1:** If we don't impose any assumptions on $R$, how can we determine $B$?
>
> **Question 2:** If $\mathrm{char} \, R > 0$, is $B$ always non-empty?

**Update 1 (11/6/2019):** As damiano had pointed out, if $R = \mathbb{F}_2$ with $n=2$, then $\mathrm{char} \, R > 0$ and the only points belonging $K_2$ is $(0,0)$, so that $B$ is empty, settling Question 2.

**Update 2 (11/7/2019):** Vic Camillo of University of Iowa and I were able to prove the following:

> **Theorem** Let $R$ be a commutative unital ring and consider $K_2$. Then the elements $(a,b) \in K_2$ are precisely those that satisfy $a = 1+u$ and $b = 1+u^{-1}$, where $u \in U(R)$ and $U(R)$ are the group of units of $R$.

*Proof* Since $K_2$ is non-empty, there exists $(a,b) \in K_2$ such that $a+b = ab$. Since $R$ is a commutative ring with identity, the expression can be rewritten as $1 = (a-1)(b-1)$ by realizing we have
\begin{align*}
0 &= ab-a-b \\
&= a(b-1) - b \\
&= a(b-1)-b+1-1 \\
&= (a-1)(b-1) -1.
\end{align*}
This means, by definition of a unit, $a-1 \in U(R)$, so $a = 1+u$ for $u \in U(R)$. Then, by the above equation, we obtain $b = 1+v$, where $v \in U(R)$ such that $uv = 1$, where $u$ is as previously stated. Denoting $v = u^{-1}$, we have $b = 1+u^{-1}$. Thus, the set of elements $(a,b) \in K_2$ are precisely those that satisfy $a = 1+u, b = 1+u^{-1}$, where $u \in U(R)$, as desired.

Thus, the structure for $K_2$ is $K_2 = \langle E \rangle \sqcup B = (0) \, \sqcup G$, where $$G = \{(a,b) \in (R\backslash \{0\})^2 \, | \, a = 1+u, b=1+u^{-1}, u \in U(R)\}.$$

Comment: What is $B$ from your Question 1 and 2?

Comment: For Q2, have you tried $n$ even and $R=\mathbb{F}_2$?

Comment: $B$ is defined to be the collection of elements $(a_i) \in K_n$ such that $a_i \neq 0_R$ for any $i$. Also, you have a point; if $R = \mathbb{F}_2$, then $\mathrm{char}(R) > 0$ and the only point in $K_2$ is $(0,0)$, hence $K_2 = \{(0)\}$, so that means $B$ is empty in this case. The settles Question 2 then.

Comment: Although I like the general problem very much (upvoted & favorite), I think that the answer to Question 1 is simply "We cannot determine $B$ without further assumptions". IMHO, the question should be rephrased in such a way that is *answerable*, e.g., "For which interesting classes of commutative rings can we show such and such results on $B$ (finiteness, simple parametrization, etc)". In other terms, what do we know about $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ that we would like to prove or disprove for different classes of rings?

Comment: Explaining my trouble with Question 1. We have $B_3 = \{ (a, b, c) \in (R \setminus \{0\})^3 \, \vert \, c = \frac{a + b}{ab - 1}\}$. So, if we are to *determine* $B$, we have to decide whether $ab - 1$ divides $a + b$ for any possible pair $(a, b)$ with non-zero sum, and this in an arbitrary unital commutative ring. This cannot be achieved in general, without any further description of the input or any algorithm to compute sums and products. I am alluding here to the part about UFD, because I don't see how prime decomposition could help in an abstract UFD.

Comment: A comment valid for *any ring $R$*. If $a_1$ is a non-zero element in the Jacobson radical of $R$, then for every $(a_2, \dots, a_{n-1}) \in (R\setminus \{0\})^{n - 2}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i \neq 0$, we can find $a_n \in R\setminus \{0\}$ such that $(a_1, \dots, a_n) \in B_n$. So we have even more *trivial solutions* in general rings.

Comment: I dunno if this helps much, but in the real numbers, the set of solutions for $n = 2$ can be parametrized by $(\sec^2(\theta), \csc^2(\theta))$, and for $n = 3$ by $(\tan(a), \tan(b), \tan(c))$ with $a + b + c = \pi$ if I remember correctly.

Comment: It would be interesting to know if $B$, corresponding to $K_n$, is non-empty for $2\le n < p$ where $char ( R)=p$ is an odd prime (at least, what happens when $R$ is a field?)